# seting auth token in react native not working

Tags: react-native

i am trying to set auth token in react native but it is not working.the api call to the url is woeking and data is saved to db but the token doesnot work

```
  axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register',
      data: Data,
 
    })
   .then(function (response) {
         console.log('working');
         ReactSession.setStoreType('Bearer', response.data.token);
         ReactSession.set('username', 'Meon');
   
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error.response.data));
      });
  }
```

i get this error
[image]

console.log(response); returns the following

[image]

Comment: Would you please print what is inside `response`? Seems like the response is missing `data` key.

Comment: @kiuQ i have added a screen shot of the responcse

Comment: The return seems to be fine. You can try print `response.data` or by pass the error with `response?.data?.token`.

Comment: @kiuQ  `response.data.token` i am getting the token i am asking how i can set it into   `ReactSession.setStoreType`

Comment: oh, sorry I misunderstand your question. May I ask that which library you are using? And the library support for react-native applications?

Comment: @kiuQ i am new to react native   i have tryed `react-native-async-storage/async-storage` but the issue is it doenot woek inside `then` of axios

Comment: As Lucas (the answer below) mentioned, the async-storage only functionable within async functions. You need to use `.then(async (responseJson) => {})` to do the work. You may edit your question with async-storage code for detail discussion.

Answer (score -2):

I use AsyncStorage together with fetch to set mine and then when i want to use it , I also call AsyncStorage from `'@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';`

After setting the state like this,

```
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
```

I try to simulate a Login

To login looks like this :

```
    FunctionLogin = async () => {
    let item = {email, password};
    fetch('http://192.168.1.101/api/auth/sign-in', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(item),
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(async (responseJson) => {
        if (responseJson.message === 'OK') {
          var token = responseJson.token;
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('email', email);
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token);
          navigation.replace('Dashboard');
        } else {
          alert(responseJson);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

To use it in any page, I use it like this , later i reference the function in useEffect

```
showdata = async () => {
    let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    alert(token);
  };
```

Suppose I want to get transaction list from my endpoint to display data I do it like this

```
getTransactionsList = async () => {
    let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    let email = await AsyncStorage.getItem('email');
    var url = 'https://192.168.1.101/api/user-data/get-transactionby-email/';

    fetch(url + email, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        setTransaction_details(responseJson);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

Then suppose i want to call it inside useEffect, I do like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    getTransactionsList();
  });
```

Thats what and how i do it and it works fine. If you also know how to use Redux, its still a good one as well.

Comment: @lucus   await AsyncStorage.setItem('email', email);
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token);  us there any whey to check in application tab of browser whthere it is saved to storage

Comment: i use React native CLI most of the time, so what i do is, once i call setItem to save on AsyncStorage , i use getItem (like i showed in the example) then show it in an alertbox, that is how i use it. You can check if u can try see it in browser with expo.

Comment: @menucd, works for both Expo and CLI tho